# Azure Table Pricing - Many, many tables

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Question,

We design our service as such that we'll be creating a lot of Azure tables.  The Azure portal only shows the cost related to the storage size.  But is there any additional cost related to keeping a lot of tables ( AWS does charge per table ).

What we're hoping is the cost will be the same either we create 100,000 small Azure tables (say all combine to be 100G)  vs  1 table with 100G.

Is this true?

Thanks.
Tim

Answer (score 0):

afaik, it's just based on size and nothing to do with number of tables.

in addition to storage size, you have to factor in transaction cost and outbound traffic...

Answer (score 0):

The azure storage charges are related to the number of bytes stored, not the number of tables per se.  Each table name does take up a miniscule amount of storage space (bytes), so there is technically a charge but even for that many it is negligible.  Arguably this would be the same as the partition key name (i.e. 1 table, with 100k partitions would require the same space as 100k tables each with one partition)

It is explained here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx

The formula is:
12 bytes + Len(TableName) * 2 bytes

So, assuming you used something like 'table000001', 'table000002', etc. the price for 100k tables would be something around $0.01 per month.